# get and set formControl, out of control

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

Is there a way to control the name of the variables when I create many forms?
I can't find even in the angular documentation

for example:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
  password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
  confirmPassword: ['', Validators.required],
  acceptTerms: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
}, {
  validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmPassword')
});
```

and when I want to get values

```
this.f['title'].value;
this.f['firstName'].value;
this.f['lastName'].value;
this.f['email'].value;
this.f['name you can not control possible errors '].value;
```

I know that it is a small example, and I can tell where the error is, but what happens if this grows too much since I had moments when I had to call the form through observables and handle it in a particular way a formControl between separate components, Maybe there is some way of not having mistakes like this.

Here I leave a small example an error that we can not handle

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-with-error-example?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: create form from JSON schema. I heard something about this never tried it though. not even googled it. Title of the question is sick ✌

Comment: I hope angular doesn't let me down

Comment: here hope this helps https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form

Comment: What is the issue? I'm having trouble understanding.. what do you mean with `name you can not control possible errors `